# When to use Expression<TDelegate>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a pure theoretical question.

When do you use `Expression<TDelegate>`, and when do you use just the `TDelegate`?

Example:

```
Func<string> myDelegate = () => "Hello World";
Expression<Func<string>> myExpression = () => "Hello World";
```

Both compile into usable code, and I can call both with the following:

```
var delegateResult = myDelegate();
var expressionResult = myExpression.Compile()();
```

So my question is.. What is the use of `Expression<TDelegate>` and what would be a situation for preferring using it over the `TDelegate` directly?

Comment: For example, whenever you'd like to inspect the AST inside the expression, you'd have to use the `Expression`, regular `Func` doesn't have such capability.